# Firebase crashlytics export data to big query

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, cloud, analytics, crashlytics

I have linked and exported firebase crashlytics data to big query.
But it is only showing the crash data after linking.
How can I get the old existing data of 90days?

I tried checking the data transfer section but did not see any option for period of data to be taken from crashlytics.

I need to export all of my existing  data to big query for further analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking the project to BigQuery, the data transfer will be configure to run once per day. It will get Crashlytics data for that specific date. This is why you are not seeing older data.

To transfer older data, you can schedule a [backfill data transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-transfers#schedule_a_backfill).

1. You would need to go to the Google Cloud [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
2. Select the project related to your Firebase project.
3. Go to BigQuery and then "Data Transfers".
4. Select "Firebase Crashlytics Export".
5. Then click on "Schedule backfill".

Comment: worked with backfill, Thanks @Gerardo.
Any idea how much time it takes for backfill? I have massive data.

Comment: That I don't know, sorry. Hopefully not that long.